# Laravel - Find out which page has the "post" in (Pagination)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm working on a "forum like" app and when viewing a thread, a user can also choose to view a post in a thread (an specific one).

The URL can be something like `/thread/29?post=22`. Now, a thread can have many posts. Therefore, since it's paginated with 10 posts per page, a post can be in any page depending on when it was posted.

I have no way of knowing which page the post is on in the record.

**Note** the pagination record is dynamic.

My code:

```
$posts = Post::where('thread_id', $thread->id)->paginate(10);
//there are over 50+ posts for instance
```

My simplified view:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)

    <span id="post{{ $post->id }}">Post #{{ $post->id }}</span>

    {{ $post->body }}

@endforeach
```

My example URL would look like: `http://example.com/thread/1`

How would I know which page has a specific post? Say I want to go to the post with ID 28 which belongs to thread with an ID 1. How would I know which page of the result that thread is in?

I want to do something like:

```
http://example.com/thread/1?post=28&page=2 //authomatically guessed that post 28 would be in page 2.
```

how can do do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more please? do you have threads that contains posts or only posts and you want them ordered or what? i couldnt understand the probleme! do you want the orders to be shown ordered? i meann like from 1 to 10 in page 1 and from 11 to 20 page 2 etc ?

Comment: Yes I want them to be ordered. So like a a thread has many posts across many pages and I want to find out which page has the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide post id by 10 and ceil value. That is of course if each post in thread starts with 1 and increments by 1.

```
$page = ceil($post->id / 10);
```

## Edit

If your post id's are dynamic then retrieve all posts from a thread ordered by post date and iterate through results to find position of searched id. I'm not a laravel developer so not sure about query syntax but something like this:

```
$searching_id = 28; // searching for page of post id 28
$post_index = 0;    // position of post in ordered posts array
$posts = Post::where('thread_id', $thread->id)->order_by('post_date'); // get all posts ordered by post_date or whatever table field is for post date
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if ($post->id == $searching_id) {
        break;
    }
    $post_index++;
}
$page = (int)($post_index / 10) + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that the paginated records is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks I did it a similar way but its 90% like your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I did it:

```
$post_id = 28;
$posts_per_page = 10;
$posts = Post::where('id', $thread->id)->get();

foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->id == $post_id) {
        $page = ceil(($key + 1) / $posts_per_page);
        break;
    }
}

// $page = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_id = 28;
$posts_per_page = 10;
$posts = Post::where('id', $thread->id)->get(['id'])->flip();
$index = $posts[$post_id]

$page = ((int) ($index / $posts_per_page) + 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!